# Prove that $g(r, \alpha, \beta) = (r\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta), r\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta), r\sin(\beta))$ is an injection.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, vector-analysis

Prove that

$g: (0,∞)×(0,2π)×(−π/2,π/2)→R^3,$

$g(r, \alpha, \beta) = (r\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta), r\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta), r\sin(\beta))$

is an injection.

Exactly what it says on the tin. I haven't gone beyond assuming $g(a,b,c) = g(c,d,e)$. After constructing the relevant system of equations I am stuck trying to equate the variables from there. I might have forgotten too much from trigonometry. This is homework, so I would appreciate if someone could walk me through the process, but not the solution.

Comment: It might be helpful to compute the Jacobian

Comment: I have done so, but...maybe I'm confused about something, but I thought Jacobian only tells about local injectivity, not global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

Put
$$g(a,b,c)=(A,B,C)$$
$$g(d,e,f)=(D,E,F)$$

then

$$g(a,b,c)=g(d,e,f) \implies$$

$$(A,B,C)=(D,E,F)\implies$$

$$A^2+B^2+C^2=D^2+E^2+F^2\implies$$
$$a^2=d^2\implies a=d$$

Comment: $a^2 = d^2$ does not imply $a=d$

Comment: Actually, it does in this case. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

First consider $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and observe that
$$
f(g(r,\alpha,\beta))=r^2\cos^2\alpha\cos^2\beta+r^2\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\beta+r^2\sin^2\beta=r^2
$$
Therefore if $g(r,\alpha,\beta)=g(s,\gamma,\delta)$, then applying $f$ to both sides yields $r^2=s^2$, hence $r=s$.

Now the equations are simpler:
$$
\begin{cases}
\cos\alpha\cos\beta=\cos\gamma\cos\delta \\[1ex]
\sin\alpha\cos\beta=\sin\gamma\cos\delta \\[1ex]
\sin\beta=\sin\delta
\end{cases}
$$
Square the first two equations and sum them, getting $\cos^2\beta=\cos^2\delta$. Since $\beta,\delta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, we obtain $\cos\beta=\cos\delta$ and now with the third equation we can conclude that $\beta=\delta$.

Finally, from $\cos\beta=\cos\delta\ne0$, we obtain $\cos\alpha=\cos\gamma$ and $\sin\alpha=\sin\gamma$, so $\alpha=\gamma$.